# Format a variable in iReport in a string with multiple fields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a text field that has the following expression:

```
$F{casNo} + " Total " + $P{chosenUom} + ": " + $V{total_COUNT}
```

`casNo` is a string, `chosenUom` is a string. `total_COUNT` is a sum variable of doubles. The `total_COUNT` variable displays, but it's got 8 - 10 decimal places (1.34324255234), all I need is something along the lines of 1.34.

Here's what I tried already:

```
$F{casNo} + " Total " + $P{chosenUom} + ": " + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($V{total_COUNT}).toString()
```

Any help would be appreciated

---

For now I'm just doing basic math, but I'm hoping for a real solution, not a workaround

```
((int)($V{total_COUNT}*100.0))/100.0
```

Comment: Why did your attempt with DecimalFormat not work for you? Did it result in an error, wrong format, etc?  That should have worked. If you received an error, then check variable type of `$V{total_COUNT}` and be sure it's never null. (Also, be aware that DecimalFormat uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN by default.)

Comment: The error I get is "[javax.servlet.ServletException: Error evaluating expression : Source text : $F{casNo} + " Total " + $P{chosenUom} + ": " + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($V{total_COUNT}).toString()] " -- But now that you mention it, I think I probably do have some null values coming from the database. All of the data comes from the users so you never know what it'll be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might split the text field into two, one containing everything but the $V{total_COUNT}, and the second containing only $V{total_COUNT}, but with the Pattern property set to something like "#0.00".

You'd have to get a bit creative with layout, though, to prevent unwanted word-wrapping and spacing; for example, first text field could be wide and right-aligned, while text field containing the count could be left-aligned and wide enough to accommodate the formatted number.

Answer (score 2):

You can format the in lline numbers by using:

```
new DecimalFormat("###0.00").format(YOUR NUMBER)
```